# How to get write unencoded html to a file?

Tags: node.js, xml-builder

I'm using reading in a .HTML snippet from the file system; it contains just `<h1>Hulton Archive</h1>`. Then I'm writing a new XML file which must contain that HTML snippet in a certain element. using XMLbuilder to build an XML file out of it. Here's what I have:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var result;

var inputFile = "html-snippet.html";
var outputFile = "test.xml";

fs.readFile(inputFile, "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log(data);

  var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: data};

  var outputXML = builder.buildObject(obj);

  fs.writeFile(outputFile, outputXML, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(outputFile + " was saved!");
    }
  });

});
```

The problem is that the HTML tags are encoded in the input file; changed from `<h1>header</h1>` into `&lt;h1&gt;header&lt;/h1&gt;`. I want to preserve the HTML tags instead of encoding them in the output file.

I have tried writing this file using both XMLbuilder (https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js) and xml2js (https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). It seems like both of them were encoding the HTML on the output file.

How can I get write out the XML file without encoding the HTML?

Comment: You'll need to use CDATA eg: https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki#cdata-nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [npm install ent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ent) you can decode the HTML after you generate the XML. This does generate "invalid" XML however. For most people, CDATA is probably the better choice.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var decode = require('ent').decode;

var result;

var inputFile = "html-snippet.html";
var outputFile = "test.xml";

fs.readFile(inputFile, "UTF-8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log(data);

  var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: data};

  var outputXML = decode(builder.buildObject(obj));

  fs.writeFile(outputFile, outputXML, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(outputFile + " was saved!");
    }
  });

});
```